# Run Time Error 424 with hidden box based off of selection

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA.  I have code for a userform that I almost have working... only problem is (commented) label and text boxes I have hidden unless the value is "Yes" is giving me a run time error.

```
Private Sub E_EnterInformation_Click()

'----------------------------------------------------
'Check Validation of Completed form
'----------------------------------------------------
If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Request By' on form", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'On Site Contact' on form", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'On Site Phone Number' on form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_EventName.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Event Name' on form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Location Number' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Off Site Delivery?' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Request Status' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Delivery Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Delivery Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show Start Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show Start Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show End Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_SETime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_SETime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show End Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Pickup Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Pickup Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

'Hide or show offsite and order number boxes

If Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value = "Yes" Then
    'EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = True          - Run Time Error 424 when No is selected on Offsite Delivery
    'EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = True        - Run Time Error 424 when No is selected on Offsite Delivery
    Else
    'EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = False         - Run Time Error 424 when Yes is selected on Offsite Delivery
    'EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = False       - Run Time Error 424 when Yes is selected on Offsite Delivery
    End If

If Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value = "Yes" And Me.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Value = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Enter Off Site Location Name and Address' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value <> "New" Then
    'EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OrderNum.Visible = True         - Run Time Error 424 when No is selected on Offsite Delivery
    'EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Visible = True       - Run Time Error 424 when No is selected on Offsite Delivery
    Else
    'EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OrderNum.Visible = False       - Run Time Error 424 when Yes is selected on Offsite Delivery
    'EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Visible = False     - Run Time Error 424 when Yes is selected on Offsite Delivery
    End If

If Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value <> "New" And Me.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Value = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OrderNum.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Enter Order/Job #' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If


'--------------------------------------------
'Enter Data in Form
'--------------------------------------------

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C6") = Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value       'Name of Requester
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C7") = Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value   'Name of Contact
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C8") = Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value    'Phone Number format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10") = Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value       'Comments (not required)

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I6") = Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value       'Name of Event
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I7") = Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.Value 'Location Number
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I8") = Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value 'Yes or No Selection
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I9") = Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value   'New or revision or cancel selection

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C9") = Me.TextBoxE_PWDate.Value          'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D9") = Me.ListBoxE_PWTime.Value          'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C10") = Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value    'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10") = Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.Value    'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C11") = Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value         'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D11") = Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.Value         'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C12") = Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value         'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D12") = Me.ListBoxE_SETime.Value         'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C13") = Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value     'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D13") = Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.Value     'Time Format

'-----------------------------------------
'Vice Versa for Revisions
'-----------------------------------------

'If Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value <> "" Then

'Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C6")
'Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C7")
'Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C8")
'Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10")
'
'Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I6")
'Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I7")
'Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I8")
'Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I9")
'
'Me.TextBoxE_PWDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C9")
'Me.ListBoxE_PWTime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D9")
'Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C10")
'Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10")
'Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C11")
'Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D11")
'Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C12")
'Me.ListBoxE_SETime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D12")
'Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C13")
'Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D13")
'
'End If

'------------------------------------------------------
'Message box when data has been correctly added
'------------------------------------------------------
'MsgBox "Show Information Added to Form", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Show Information Added to Form"

Me.Hide

Call ESaveBook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment Request").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment Request").Select

End Sub
```

Sorry for the large amount of code included... it basically is a userform that is used to enter information and when you finish, it hides and then when you press a revise button, it shows again with the same information previously entered (which is what should be in the excel boxes.

Why would I be receiving this error?

Comment: *Sorry for the large amount of code included* - you could refactor your code to handle the `Change` event for each of the fields (textboxes, listboxes) to invoke some `Private Sub ValidateForm()` procedure that vaildates each field and only enables the `E_EnterInformation` button when all fields are valid - that way the `Click` handler wouldn't need to have that much code. Plus you could replace all these obnoxious `MsgBox` warnings with elegant error/validation icons with tooltips indicating what's wrong.

Comment: What is `EquipmentRequest`? Shouldn't that be `Me`?

Comment: Dang it Mathieu... you were right.  I was referencing the userform name, but looks like I don't need to do so.  Thank you, of course it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `EquipmentRequest` used to be the name of your form, *and* `Option Explicit` isn't specified at the top of the module to require variable declaration.

Without `Option Explicit`, an unknown identifier (such as `EquipmentRequest`) is silently turned into a local `Variant/Empty` variable... and when a member call is made against that variable, it fails with error 424, because `Empty` isn't an object agaisnt which you can make a member call - hence "object required".

Looks like you were in the middle of replacing all `EquipmentRequest` references to the *default instance* of the form with `Me` qualifiers - but forgot a few.

- Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of *every* module. Always. Make it a habit. Code won't compile until all variables are declared.
- Remove any/all references to the form's *default instance* (i.e. `EquipmentRequest`, `UserForm1`, or whatever the name of your form is), replace them with `Me` (which is the *current instance* of the class you're looking at).

As for the huge amount of code, that's because the *Single Responsibility Principle* is... well, taking a beating: the large chunk at the top is responsible for validating the form - pull that concern into its own procedure scope. For example:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ValidateForm
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateForm()
    Dim validationErrors As Long

    If Trim$(Me.TextBox1.Text) = vbNullString Then
        Me.InvalidIconTextBox1.Visible = True
        validationErrors = validationErrors + 1
    Else
        Me.InvalidIconTextBox1.Visible = False
    End If

    '...

    Me.OkButton.Enabled = (validationErrors = 0)
End Sub
```

Where `InvalidIconTextBox1` could be an `Image` control with a little 16x16 bitmap and a user-friendly tooltip text - that would remove the need for all these `MsgBox` calls, and make all validation errors visible at once - and the `OkButton` couldn't be clicked with invalid data.

Comment: So, what's odd is the form is actually called EquipmentRequest still.  Changing it to 'Me' helped, but I will refer to this later in my programming as I will have 2 versions of this (revision path) that I will be making soon that this advice may come in handy.